# "Lost connection to MySQL server" error, but 1 hour after actual occurrence?

Tags: php, mysql, timeout

During high load on our platform we start seeing some errors from MySQL in our logs. The strange thing about these errors are they appear in the logs exactly 1 hour (3600 seconds) after they actually occurred.

For example, we did a load test the other day, and at around 8.30am we hit a bottle neck and things started timing out. Exactly 1 hour later at 9.30am we started seeing the following lines in our logs,

```
... Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli_Exception [0] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104 ...
```

I've been trying to find a timeout setting for PHP's `mysqli` or `libmysql` related to this, but I'm struggling to find one that explains our problem.

Any ideas?

Closest I got to was [`mysqlnd.net_read_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/apis-php-mysqlnd.config.html#apis-php-mysqlnd.net-read-timeout), which although is yet to 1 year, mentions TCP/IP timeouts, which after further Googling got me to [TCP session timeout](http://www.ipv4security.com/packet_flow/tcp_timeout.txt), which appears to be 3600 by default. I am however very aware I'm probably going down the wrong road here.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make absolutely sure: Those log message really _occur_ an hour later; it's not just a time zone +/-1h thingy?

Comment: does this error ocurrs only when you do this high load?

Comment: @VolkerK They physically appear in the log stream exactly 1 hour after the period of high load. I saw it happen with my own eyes.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using master-slave replication for Mysql?

If your master goes down and comes back up, the slave isn't notified instantly. It stays waiting on the same connection until it reaches the timeout which is by default 1 hour (3600 seconds). After timeout, it will reconnect with new connection and hence logs the errors that were caused.

Comment: That's interesting. I saw something `net slave` related in MySQL while Googling. In our case, the master does get rather warm, but doesn't actually go down. Reckon there's a blip and the connections on the slaves suffer from this timeout?